# I moved `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/` to trash and can't find it

Tags: 12.04, undelete

I moved `/usr/share/gimp/2.0/` to trash and now I can't find it.

Is it gone because I moved it from a root owned directory to the trash?

Is there a place I can download the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `sudo ls /root/.local/share/Trash/files`